# Delaying a queue for a finite time, conditionally

Tags: swift, timer, grand-central-dispatch

How could I delay a background queue's execution, without using sleep? Further, how could I interrupt that delay if needs be?

The docs for `RunLoop` suggest a while loop around the function `run` with a custom condition in the while loop. But how would I setup a timer to toggle the while loops execution?

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do that? Wha's the goal behind it? That's in case you are taking your issue your wrong way, and your solution isn't the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`suspend`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchobject/1452801-suspend) custom dispatch queues (but not global queues nor main queue). That stops new tasks from starting on that queue, but it does not affect things already running on that queue. You can [`resume`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchobject/1452929-resume) to start running items that had previously been dispatched to the queue, but had not yet started.

GCD also provides a native mechanism to [`cancel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/1780910-cancel) a particular work item, and dispatch it again later when you want execution to resume. Note that `cancel` does not perform preemptive cancellation, but rather only sets a Boolean, [`isCancelled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/1780829-iscancelled/), which your dispatched task would need to periodically check and manually exit.

(If you want to cancel tasks on a queue, you might consider `OperationQueue`, as that has more graceful cancelation capabilities than dispatch queues. Or you might consider the “structured concurrency” of `async`-`await` of [Swift concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID642), which also has cancelation built-in.)

---

Now, while GCD does not have a notion of “suspending” a task dispatched to a background thread, you might be able to jury-rig something something with a very careful use a semaphores. But the details would vary greatly based upon your implementation, so it is hard to advise further without more details.

---

You asked:

> The docs for `RunLoop` suggest a `while` loop around the function `run` with a custom condition in the `while` loop.

As a general rule, anything that involves spinning in a `while` loop is to be avoided. It is s very inefficient pattern and is to be avoided. Many years ago (e.g. before GCD, before `URLSession`, etc.), this spin-on-run-loop pattern was not unheard of (e.g., it was the go-to technique for running `NSURLConnection` on a background thread), but it is an anachronism nowadays. It is an inefficient approach; an anti-pattern.